# Dominar only starts when I press the clutch( even if its in neutral)

Tags: motorcycle, bajaj

My Dominar was completely submerged during the recent Kerala floods and is now with the service center for more than a month. The headlight, ECU was replaced (also some valves connecting the engine). The service center called me and said that all is fixed except that **there is an issue as the bike won't start without holding the clutch even if it's in neutral**. 
Their assessment is that it's because of some faulty sensors or wiring and has to replace the entire system to fix it and will cost around 12000 Rs and they are not sure if it will cover under the insurance. 
I always try to keep my bike in perfect condition and it is very disheartening to see these kinds of issues.

- My question is should I replace this entire sensor system (even if I
  have to pay for it)? The logic being it can also cause more issues in the future and it is better to fix it right now.
- Also, things they may have missed
  which can also cause this issue (which I can ask them to check).

Actually very confused right now and is looking for a second opinion.

Comment: You pays your money and takes your choice. Either get them to sort it correctly and pay now or pay loads later to sort many problems...

Answer (score 1):

god bless the flood victims. Apparently lot of other motor vehicles were also damaged. As the motorcycle get submerged water enters through all the open holes i.e. Exhausts, open electrical wiring and electronic chips. since water is a conductor it might have destroyed the electrical circuitry including the fuses and ECU chips.

The water since entered through the exhaust and entered the catalytic converter too which basically allowed water to enter the engine too (probably).

things you can try with service center to figure out the issue are -

- ECU re-flashing
- Water in catalytic converter
- checking electrical system under the rider seat for blown fuses or rusted wires.
- Clutch wire issues with the ignition system

The scenario you said that it only works when clutch is pressed, happens also when the bike is in first gear and you need the clutch lever to be pressed and then only it turns on. Hope fully some smart mechanic might be able to figure out the issue. Ask for good service center around with proven knowledge from any of your friend.

It is probable that some sensor isn't detecting that bike is in neutral and thus asking for clutch to be pressed. When in neutral the dashboard should show green "N" else the gear sensor is faulty.

First get the above parts checked for surity that there is no other way to fix it. Moving on go with replacing everything that can affect it. Since it is going to cost a lot and insurance might refuse, play the "dog came on the road card" and get things fixed and fool the insurance companies although it is not fooling since they should pay for the damage but they might refuse. If the cost does not affect you much go for the replacements as there seems no other way of fixing it.

Hope this helps!